# Does someone knows how to preform Camera-IMU time offset using GTSAM?

Tags: slam-algorithm

Now I have the camera pose and IMU measurement where there exists a time-offset between them? How to model this problem in a factor graph and do estimation use GTSAM, Do someone ever did similar works before? Any advice is needed. Thanks!